# how grep with the specified string and store the values in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Below is my input file,

```
Server:         172.16.249.150
Address:        172.16.249.150#53

Non-authoritative answer:
cloud-us-east.digital-element.net       canonical name = usa.cloud.netacuity.com.
usa.cloud.netacuity.com canonical name = us-east.cloud.netacuity.com.
us-east.cloud.netacuity.com     canonical name = de-prod-nacs.elasticbeanstalk.com.
de-prod-nacs.elasticbeanstalk.com       canonical name = awseb-prod-nacs-397853066.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   awseb-prod-nacs-397853066.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.243.94.244
Name:   awseb-prod-nacs-397853066.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.243.113.63
```

i want a output like below,
54.243.94.244
54.243.113.63

only last two ip address,

Also input file may vary in future it may have lot of ip address at the end. so i need to exclude the first ip alone. how to achieve this unix? please suggest some commands. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better would be to use `dig` instead of `nslookup`; its `+short` mode includes no extraneous data in output, reducing the amount of postprocessing needed.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward for that given input file:

```
$ grep "Address:" input.txt  | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tail -2
54.243.94.244
54.243.113.63
```

Or:

```
$ nslookup cloud-us-east.digital-element.net  | grep "Address:"  | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tail -2
```

Single line, add a pipe to tr:

```
$ nslookup cloud-us-east.digital-element.net  | grep "Address:"   | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tail -2 | tr '\012' ' '
54.243.94.244 54.243.113.63
```

For a 'host' lookup:

```
$ host cloud-us-east.digital-element.net | tr ' ' '\012' | grep -vi "[a-z]"
54.243.113.63
54.243.94.244
```

EDIT:

For 'nslookup' to skip the nameserver:

```
$ nslookup cloud-us-east.digital-element.net  | grep "Address:" | grep -v "#"  | awk -F: '{print $2}' 
54.243.113.63
54.243.94.244
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried this but input file may vary in future it may have lot of ip address at the end. so i need to exclude the first ip alone.

Comment: So long as the infile is of the 'nslookup' variety, where the first skippable address: line contains an ip address suffixed with #53, you can grep it out. Edited the Answer to reflect this.